# Main method DriverMortgageClass.java

Tags: java, main-method

I am close to completing this program but it cannot run because it needs a main method. However whenever I enter it I recieve the error code illegal start of expression. Can someone point out where the main method belongs in this code snippet? Bellow is the code I have written. I have also been instructed to use the Javadoc utility tool and am still unsure of what that is and how to use it. I believe I am on the right track by using java.util.doc

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DriverMortgageClass
{


   public double annualInterestRate;
   public int numberOfYears;
   public double loanAmount;
   public double monthlyPayment;
   public double totalPayment;

  
   //set decimal format
   DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat ("0.00");
   
   private Mortgage mortgage;
   
   public DriverMortgageClass()
   {
   
   mortgage = new Mortgage();
   }

public void start()
{
  
//get input for interest rate
String annualInterestRateString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter yearly interest rate, for example 8.25",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
annualInterestRate=Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRateString);
mortgage.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate);

//get input for number of years
String numberOfYearsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number of years as an integer, for example 5",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
numberOfYears= Integer.parseInt(numberOfYearsString);
mortgage.setNumberOfYears(numberOfYears);

//set loan amount
String loanAmountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter loan amount, for example 120000.95",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
loanAmount= Integer.parseInt(loanAmountString);
mortgage.setLoanAmount(loanAmount);


//calculate the monthly and total payment
monthlyPayment=loanAmount*annualInterestRate /(1-(Math.pow(1/(1+annualInterestRate),numberOfYears*12)));
totalPayment=monthlyPayment*numberOfYears*12;

//display monthly and total payment
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The monthly payment is"+monthlyPayment 
+"The total payment is"+totalPayment);
       

System.exit(0);
}// end main method
}
```

Comment: I also have another program that goes with this one that encapsulates information not included in this file. If it is needed I am able to provide that as well but all I really need to know is where is the correct place to input my main method so that my program will run.

Comment: A main method must have the signature `public static void main(String[])`. You don't have a method like this. Therefore, you don't have a main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it needs a main method

Then add a main method and JavaDoc

```
/**
*  This is a JavaDoc. Describe the class here. 
*
**/
public class DriverMortgageClass
{


    // Other code...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DriverMortgageClass().start();
    } 
}
```